# Select distinct... in fulltext search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

```
    <?php session_start(); 
    $user =$_GET['user']; 
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","...","...");
    mysql_select_db("..."); 
$sql= "SELECT filter FROM userfilter WHERE user='$user'"; 
$mksql = mysql_query($sql); while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($mksql)) {    
$filter=$row['filter'];     
    $sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM rss WHERE MATCH(content,title) AGAINST ('$filter')";    
    $mksql2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($mksql2))
    { echo .....    } 
    ?>
```

If  I have two rows content that contains the $filter ,it outputs me that content but it's repeating.
For example:

> title|content
>
> asd  |This is a sample content ,number one
>
> das
> |This is a
> sample content ,number two

....

And if my keywords are "sample" and "number" ,it outputs me twice the title and the content.How to prevent that?

Comment: I don't know how and why but when  I added a dot before = in $filter = $_POST['filter'] it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should combine your first result, and issue single query instead doing a loop and query

```
$filters = array();
while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($mksql)) 
{
  $filters[$row['filter']] = '+'.$row['filter'];
}
/* free result */

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM rss ".
        "WHERE MATCH(content,title) ".
        "AGAINST ('".implode(' ', $filters)."' in boolean mode)";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works but may not be the most effective way:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(Description) AGAINST ('$filter') AS score FROM table
WHERE score > 1
GROUP BY score, id;
```

This way you'll get one row per match score per id.

Comment: It outputs and content that doesn't contain the keywords

Comment: Sorry, I added the required where clause so that rows with no content won't be returned.

Comment: Unknown column 'score' in 'where clause'